# rails 4 route with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my route settings

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    get 'message'
  end      
end
```

It works fine but  I would like to add a parameter to this route

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    get 'message/:username'
  end      
end
```

I got an error when I ran `rake routes`

```
rake aborted!
missing :action
/home/li/data/git/projectname/config/routes.rb:5:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/li/data/git/projectname/config/routes.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/li/data/git/projectname/config/routes.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/li/data/git/projectname/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/li/data/git/projectname/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/li/data/git/projectname/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is the right way to add a parameter to this route?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    get 'message/:username' => :message
  end      
end
```

If you want to use `messages_message_url` and `messages_message_path`, use a named route with the `as:` option:

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    get 'message/:username' => :message, as: 'messages_message'
  end      
end
```

Comment: why `get 'message/:username' => 'message'` not working?

Comment: @wwli I'm not sure, I think `get 'message'` is a shortcut for `get 'message' => 'message'`, and it can't work with dynamic segment.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, I tried to run `rake routes`  how come the prefix is empty. And I tried to use `message_messages_path`  I met an error `undefined method `message_messages_path` Some setting I am missing for this route?